# How does serverless know where to find the serverless.yml?

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, serverless-framework, serverless

How does npm/yarn serverless packageadded locally in a project know where to locate the serverless.yml file?
I am trying to locate the exact piece of code in the source code of serverless framework ( https://github.com/serverless/serverless), where this happens, but haven't had any luck so far.
I need to know this because my

```
       yarn sls offline start
```

command does not seem to the new changes that i did in serverless.yml file.
It keeps picking the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code used by Serverless to load the configuration:

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/utils/getServerlessConfigFile.js#L9

Relevant excerpt:

```
  const servicePath = srvcPath || process.cwd();
  const jsonPath = path.join(servicePath, 'serverless.json');
  const ymlPath = path.join(servicePath, 'serverless.yml');
  const yamlPath = path.join(servicePath, 'serverless.yaml');
  const jsPath = path.join(servicePath, 'serverless.js');

  return BbPromise.props({
    json: fileExists(jsonPath),
    yml: fileExists(ymlPath),
    yaml: fileExists(yamlPath),
    js: fileExists(jsPath),
  }).then(exists => {
```

Note that from the CLI `servicePath` is set to the current working directory.

Looking at the code, my guess is that you may have a `serverless.json` which takes precedence over `serverless.yaml`? The command `serverless print` will show your resolved configuration. (https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/print/#print)